# Mathematica default magnification

Tags: magnification

I read a previous post that told me to use this fucntion

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 96}
]
```

to change my default magnification but now I have an error that doesn't allow me to use *Mathematica* at all. The error is

> "The specified setting for the option FontProperties, ScreenResolution cannot be used."

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is your version of Mathematica?  Try to go to Evaluation -> Quite Kernel -> Local

Comment: I cant even open a notebook. It crashes at the start page of mathematica.

Comment: Try no to open the kernel version. In windows this is in the DOS command. Can you start the command line version (math.exe)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Does the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+O work?

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work:

Go to Format -> Options Inspector, and change the default Notebook Magnification after selecting Global Preferences in the top left dropdown.

[image]

Comment: i have a windows computer. Do you know how to do that on windows?

Comment: @MelRich As far as I'm aware there's no difference.